# Spring Cloud - Redis Rate Limiting - Not working for request per minute

Tags: java, redis, spring-cloud, gateway

My particular use case is I want to implement the rate limiting at the spring cloud gateway using redis rate limiter e.g. 4 requests per minute for particular route.

But it is not working as expected it automatically fills bucket as soon as one request completed. Used the same implementation as provided by the spring cloud forum but not able to limit my request for particular time window:

Rate limits bellow 1 request/s are accomplished by setting replenishRate to the wanted number of requests, requestedTokens to the timespan in seconds and burstCapacity to the product of replenishRate and requestedTokens, e.g. setting replenishRate=1, requestedTokens=60 and burstCapacity=60 will result in a limit of 1 request/min.

TIA

Comment: Also is there a way to chanage the replenish rate time from second to minutes. redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate property is how many requests per second you want a user to be allowed to do, without any dropped requests. This is the rate at which the token bucket is filled.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after updating spring cloud version to 2020.0.2

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: I''ll post the solution who those could not do that, requestedToken is the key that you can use that for managing tokes by minute. if you specify the config below, you will limit requests by 5r/min. 
   
redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 90
redis-rate-limiter.requestedTokens: 30